# How to reference an Activity from within an Aspect

Tags: android, android-activity, aop, aspectj, aspect

I currently have the current aspect

```
@Aspect
public class ActivityShowingAspect {

    private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD =
            "execution(@nz.co.kevinsahandsomedevil.android.myaccount.aspect.ActivityMustBeShowing * *(..))";

    @Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD)
    public void methodAnnotatedWithActivityShowing() {
    }

    @Around("methodAnnotatedWithActivityShowing()")
    public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Activity activity = // code to retrieve the calling activity, joinPoint.getTarget() or whatever
        Object result = null;
        if(!activity.isFinishing()) {
            result = joinPoint.proceed();
        } else {
            result = // do something else
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I'd like to know how to determine the calling `Activity` from within the Aspect.

Comment: Aren't you already doing that with the `!activity.isFinishing()` in your code ? Can you be more descriptive about what you consider not finishing ?

Comment: @XGouchet hi editted the question - I'm actually asking how to retrieve the Activity from within the aspect. Was confused after reading it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it depends on where the method with your annotation is.

If the annotated method is declared within an Activity implementation, then you can indeed call `joinpoint.getTarget()`and cast the result.

Also you might want to update your pointcut to make sure that the method indeed is on an activity :

```
 execution(@nz.co.vodafone.android.myaccount.aspect.ActivityMustBeShowing * *(..)) && within(android.app.Activity+)
```

If that's not the case then you might need to add an advice before any activity's `onResume()` to remember what the current activity is.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not going to restrict it within an Activity since I'm planning on calling it within Fragments as well, but that makes sense. Just a quick follow up; what should be my `result` within `else`? (code above)

Comment: Well it depends on the type redirected by your method, so you probably want either to return null (which cover any object), or add a parameter to your annotation to set the default value to return : @ActivityMustBeShowing(defaultValue = "foo")